# How to send message to node js socket.io server from django server?

Tags: node.js, django

I have a node.js socket.io server as well as django server. Socket server has some clients connected with it. Now I want to send some messages from django server to the socket.io server so that it can broadcast these messages to its connected client.

Currently I am using pubsub by creating a redis server. But it's not working and no connection request is created with nodejs server:

Please suggest me a good way.
Thanks in advance.

**Code in django:**

```
import redis
client = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=5)
client.publish('message', json.dumps({'query': {'token': jwt.encode({'user': 'admin'}, settings.SOCKET_SECRET_TOKEN, algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')}}))
```

**Code from nodejs server:**

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const SECRET_KEY = '*******************************';
const port = 3000;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

server.listen(3000, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

io.use(function(socket, next){
  if (socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token){
    jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, SECRET_KEY, function(err, decoded) {
      if(err) return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
      socket.decoded = decoded;
      next();
    });
  } else {
      next(new Error('Authentication error'));
  }    
})
.on('connection', function(socket) {  
  console.log("Co nnection established");

  socket.on('message', function(message) {
    io.emit('message', message);
  });
});
```